# java.lang.InternalError: couldn't create component peer

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am getting an **intermittent** error when clicking the "Play" button on my game.

Sometimes it works and starts the game fine, other times it stops running the game and throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: couldn't create component peer
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.checkCreation(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WCanvasPeer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WPanelPeer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WFramePeer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.createFrame(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.setUpDisplay(TerrainDemo.java:3363)
at Joehot200.TerrainDemo.startGame(TerrainDemo.java:3434)
at StartScreenExperiments.Test2.resartTDemo(Test2.java:55)
at StartScreenExperiments.Test2.main(Test2.java:41)
```

Line 3363 in SetUpDisplay() is:

```
frame = new JFrame();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setDimensions(50, 50);
        frame.setVisible(true); //This is line 3363
        try {
            Display.setParent(canvas);
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

I just cannot find a solution to this. Especially since the error is intermittent and cannot always be reproduced.

Comment: Give the frame a size...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Unfortunately that did not fix the issue.